# How to kill descendant processes correctlly by systemctrl stop

Tags: linux, systemd

### Problem

My service creates three processes, **A** --spawns-- **B** --spawns--**C**. When I call `systemctl stop myservice`, **A** and **B** are killed, keeping **C** process alived everytime, caussing next-time starting of the service failing.

### Background

I register a system service by adding a configuration file `/usr/lib/systemd/system/SysChecker.service` and here's the file:

```sh
[Unit]
Description=SysChecker Tool
After=local-fs.target

[Service]
PIDFile=/var/run/syschecker_tool.pid
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/SysChecker.sh start
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

In which I specified a **PIDFILE** to store the main process ID. The writting of the process ID is arranged in `Syschecker.sh` after the python script executed.

The main logic of `SysChecker.sh` is:

```sh
# Execute the python script.
su - omm -c "export PATH=${path};export PYTHONPATH=${pyPath};export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${libPath};nohup python3 a_script.py" &

# find the python script process ID then store it to the file.
ps -ef |grep 'su - omm -c export' |grep -v -w grep |awk '{print $2}' > /var/run/syschecker_tool.pid
```

### Behavior

`systemctl start SysChecker` starts three python processes:

```sh
root     53494  0.0  0.0  96628  6060 ?        S    19:53   0:00 su - omm -c export PATH=/opt/SysChecker/PythonLib/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin;export PYTHONPATH=/opt/SysChecker/PythonLib/lib/python3.8:;export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/SysChecker/PythonLib/lib;nohup python3 /opt/SysChecker/SysCheck/Lib/runRestserver.py
omm      53500  0.0  0.0  13452  3176 ?        Ss   19:53   0:00 -bash -c export PATH=/opt/SysChecker/PythonLib/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin;export PYTHONPATH=/opt/SysChecker/PythonLib/lib/python3.8:;export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/SysChecker/PythonLib/lib;nohup python3 /opt/SysChecker/SysCheck/Lib/runRestserver.py
omm      53525  0.0  0.0 186504 30944 ?        Sl   19:53   0:00 python3 /opt/SysChecker/SysCheck/Lib/runRestserver.py
```

`systemctl status SysChecker`, everything look good:

```sh
● SysChecker.service - SysChecker Tool
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/SysChecker.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2021-04-29 19:53:55 CST; 49min ago
 Main PID: 53494 (su)
    Tasks: 0 (limit: 512)
   CGroup: /system.slice/SysChecker.service
           ‣ 53494 su - omm -c export PATH=/opt/SysChecker/PythonLib/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:...

Apr 29 19:53:55 8-5-156-13 systemd[1]: Started SysChecker Tool.
Apr 29 19:53:55 8-5-156-13 SysChecker[53473]: ..done
Apr 29 19:53:55 8-5-156-13 su[53494]: (to omm) root on none
Apr 29 19:53:55 8-5-156-13 su[53494]: pam_unix(su-l:session): session opened for user omm by (uid=0)
```

And when `systemctl stop SysChecker; ps aux | grep runRest | grep -v grep`, the grandson process always remains:

```sh
omm      53525  0.0  0.0 186504 30944 ?        Sl   19:53   0:00 python3 /opt/SysChecker/SysCheck/Lib/runRestserver.py
```

### My thoughts

Main process and their descendents should be killed by systemd, accordding to documentation of systemd:

> If set to control-group, all remaining processes in the control group of this unit will be killed on unit stop
> ...
> Defaults to control-group.

But **C** remains. Any ideas will be very appreciated.

Comment: Give systemd 90 seconds to kill it. You did not give time for the process to react. `find the python script process ID then store it to the file.` Why would you do that? Can't you just run the python script? Why the shell wrapper? `grep 'su - omm -c export'` Sure it remains, you only grepped for you `su`, not for `python`, so systemd killed the pid in the pid file. But... what for the pid file?

Comment: @KamilCuk Hi, tks for your comment. As far as I know, I only need to use `grep 'su -omm -c export'` to grab the main process Id and systemd will kill all processes that related to the main one by default. Actually, I tried using `grep 'runRestserver.py'`, which makes things worse--my service would keep restarting regardless it has been booted successfully when I call `systemctl start SysChecker`

Comment: But _why_? Just run the python script. I see the documentation also states, that using `PIDFile` should be avoided. Why are you using it at all? And - your service should be Type=forking, because your main process forks. But instead, _do not fork_, set Type=simple and be done with it. `I only need to use`, no, don't use it at all. And if you do, use `pgrep`. And do not use `ps | grep` to find pid - make your python script write it's own pid to the pid file, if you really want that. But instead, do not fork at all.